# Vim -- Syntax highlighting depending on whether whole line is commented

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to have vim highlight folds differently depending on whether every line in a fold is only comments or whitespace? In that case, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the fold highlighting, as there's only one highlight group for all folds ([`:help hl-Folded`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-Folded)). What you can do is indicate the "all comments"-nature of a fold via a custom [`fold-foldtext`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold-foldtext); for example, you could prepend `COMMENTED:`. It would then look like this:

```
+--  3 lines: # some stuff here

COMMENTED: +--  3 lines: # comment

command 2
command 3
```

The second part of a solution is determining whether all lines inside a fold are actually comments. This could be done by querying the syntax highlighting (via [`synID()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#synID%28%29)), which would be universal, but also cumbersome and potentially slow. If all you care about is fully commented lines with a comment prefix, you could obtain that from [`'comments'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27comments%27) for the current filetype and manually match against it. (My [ingo-library plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) has a [function](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ingo-library/blob/aff2fce2b85f7de50ce429fb9bc77687df5d3616/autoload/ingo/comments.vim#L62) for that.) If all you care about is a simple, generic comment prefix like `#` (as used in shell scripts, Perl, etc.), a simple pattern match will do, like this:

```
function! CommentIndicator()
    for l:lnum in range(v:foldstart, v:foldend)
        if getline(l:lnum) !~# '^\s*#'
            " This fold is not fully commented.
            return ''
        endif
    endfor
    return 'COMMENTED: '
endfunction

let &foldtext = 'CommentIndicator() . foldtext()'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Actually, you can use `foldmethod=expr`.

As an example:

`set foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\s*'.&commentstring[0]`

You can see full answer with similiar problem here: [[1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3513)].

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I understand it, this only lets me fold the comments selectively. I'm fine with the method of folding, but I would like to have the folded lines highlighted differently depending on whether they only constitute comments.